# Ubuntu 20.04 suddenly freezes in dock menu and does not respond

Tags: 20.04

Even though my PC's hardware is adequate for Ubuntu 20.04, it suddenly freezes in the dock menu while browsing and all icons fade away. Moreover, it does not even respond when I try `xkill` command.

Here is some info about my system:

[image: System info]

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your vm.swappiness=10 is a totally incorrect value for your system.

Set vm.swappiness=60 (based on 8G RAM and 4G SWAP), this way...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/sysctl.conf` # edit this file

Search for an existing `vm.swappiness=` entry...

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> vm.swappiness

- If found, **edit** it to say `vm.swappiness=60`
- If not found, **add** `vm.swappiness=60` at the end of the file

Save your edits and quit gedit

`sudo sysctl -p`